# Always disable paste 

Tags: wpf, copy, paste, cut

For a "common" look and feel I have an app that shows the paste/cut/copy buttons in a ribbon but I want to have paste always disabled no matter what field is selected. How do I approach this?

Comment: So you have a paste button which you never want to use?

Answer (score 1):

By default all the controls in WPF have a default `ContextMenu` that allows copy, paste and cut. You can disable this menu by setting this property as `“{x:Null}”`, but the keys associated with the menu options still work. In order to disable this commands we can use the `DataObject` class, which have handlers to attach any `DepencencyObject` in case on Copy or Paste:

```
DataObject.AddPastingHandler(control, this.OnCancelCommand);
DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(control, this.OnCancelCommand);
```

Finally in the event handler we need to cancel the current command:

```
private void OnCancelCommand(object sender, DataObjectEventArgs e)
{
    e.CancelCommand();
}
```

The CancelCommand method will cancel any `ApplicationCommand.Copy, ApplicationCommand.Paste` and ApplicationCommand.Cut sent over the control.Now if you want to enable copying than delete the dateobject calling `AddCopyingHandler` code and it will work than.